# Closing task on lead without going to task page

Tags: salesforce-id, leads, tasks

I want to close the task on lead list page without going to task page an close. I just want to close the task by clicking cls link in front of created task. Please guide me, how can i do this.

Comment: I don't think you can do it as a link next to each task. But if you're ok with selecting checkboxes next to these tasks and then clicking "Complete all" button or something like that - check out http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/creating-a-custom-list-view-button-that-handles-multi-record-selection