# Mass select checkbox not appearing in visualforce list view page

Tags: list-view

When I open standard list view page of Account I am able to see mass select checkbox as below

[image]

But when I try to replicate this using VF page with `apex:listViews`,mass select checkbox do not appear.

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding this the limitation of apex:ListViews. You will need to write custom code for getting that check box there and adding action on it. 
here is examplele that will help you. [Creating a custom list-view button that handles multi-record selection](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/creating-a-custom-list-view-button-that-handles-multi-record-selection)