# Issues on a LIST button

Tags: visualforce, security, master-detail, field-level-security

I have a list button that on clicking take me to page **/apex/abc** . In that page I have a input field called account :  **order__c.account__c** that is a master detail child to Accounts and a button.

My problem is:

With my **admin** profile, I'm able to view the field properly on the visualforce page, but on logging with a profile **Sales Manager** when I click the list button, it takes me to the visualforce page, but I can't see the field or the button.

I have check the following:

1.**Sales Manager** profile can view accounts and has read only access to child **order__c**

2. FLS for the object order__c is Visible and required(MD relation)
3. Has profile access for both visualforce page and apex class

Am I missing something? Please guide me.

Comment: If the Sales Manager Profile only has read access on the field then they will not see the input field as VF respects FLS. Not sure about the button without some page markup to look at

Comment: Hi @Eric. On second check, I found Sales Manger profile has Visible and required and not read only. Let me correct the question

Comment: @MnZ:Can u post your code.i do have a similar requirement.Where On clicking the list button ,u get the child records displayed related to that particular parent record.

Comment: Mine is a simple search button. On clicking, records are displayed on a table. If you want I can share. Came across this one..  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/creating-a-custom-list-view-button-that-handles-multi-record-selection

Comment: @MnZ - You say: "read only access to child order__c" which means they are not able to edit the record and thus will NOT see the input field