# Update Check-Box on Opportunity List View

Tags: button

I would like to create a button that appears on an Opportunity List View, when selected, allows me to update a checkbox field [Mark_As_Paid__c] for all the opportunities selected in the view.

Attached is a screen shot of the Opportunity List View that I'm referring to. The custom field check-box that I want the button to update is called "Mark_As_Paid__c"
[image]

Comment: If you need a more robust solution to do more than just that one taks check this out -  [Creating a custom list-view button that handles multi-record selection](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/creating-a-custom-list-view-button-that-handles-multi-record-selection)

Comment: @Eric Eh. I think the VF page is total overkill for something that can be typed up in five minutes. If you find an example that mimics my answer, then I'd consider this a duplicate.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Did not see your answer in the review, I agree. Retracted my vote and let link for reference in case it becomes "but then I want to do x.y.z"

Comment: @eric, Thank you for you assistance. I'm new to stackexchange. Is there a way to send you a direct or private message? Thanks, David

Comment: @davidw no  sfse does not have messaging

Answer (score 2):

You can use the AJAX Toolkit to do this. Here's what that looks like:

```
{!RequireScript('/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js')}

var oppIds = {!GetRecordIds($ObjectType.Opportunity)}, opps = [];
[].forEach.call(oppIds, function(v) {
    var opp = new sforce.SObject('Opportunity');
    opp.Id = v;
    opp.Mark_as_Paid__c = true;
    opps.push(opp);
});
var results = sforce.connection.update(opps);
// process results
```

See the [Examples of Synchronous Calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm) document in the AJAX Toolkit manual for more information. They also discuss how to handle error messages and so on.

Also, see [GetRecordIds](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#GETRECORDIDS) for how that works.

Comment: sfdcfox, thank you very much. I really appreciate your assistance.