# How to execute Apex code from Custom Object List View in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: apex, lightning, list-view, action

**Example**

I would like to add a quick action button to the list view page for custom object `Invoice__c`, the quick action is called `Generate Invoices` and when executed will run apex code to generate 100 `Invoice__c` records.

---

I would like to add a quick action to a custom object list view in Salesforce Lightning which opens a Lightning Component.

But as far as I can see it is not possible (at the moment).

So, what are my options for triggering/executing some Apex code from a custom object list view?

Comment: Is this for Lightning or Classic?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your use case? As what is the expected functionality from related list?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Visualforce List view button and then from Visualforce page can call your apex code. Once the execution is complete you can redirect back to List view

[image]

[Adding Custom List Buttons using Standard List Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_custom_button.htm)

[Use Visualforce in Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_intro)

Comment: this is particularly helpful too: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/creating-a-custom-list-view-button-that-handles-multi-record-selection